# how to transfer data from a python file and use it inside a different python file?

Tags: python-3.x

hello every one am still new to the world of python so excuse my noob question here :

supposing that i have a python file named calculator1.py
which gives me the value of i as the following example

```
j=0
i=0
while j<=5:
     if type(j/2)==int:
          i+=1
     j+=1
```

after that i will need the value of i to use it in a separate python file named calculator2.py

so how to extract the value of i from one python file and insert it into a different python file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can import the variable by in your other python file (calculator2.py).
So

```
from calculator1 import i
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tested this by creating a variable, looping through range 4 and increasing the variables value by 1, and then I imported the variable in another file and the value was 4.

Comment: test.py: 
`i = 0
for number in range(0,4):
    i+=1
`
test2.py:
`from test import i
print(i)
`
>py .\test2.py
4

Comment: No, I was incorrect, appologize. I overlooked the fact in this specific case that the imported module is immediately executed when imported. Had i been updated in a function in the imported module, *then* it would not work. Still it feels not 'right' to do it this way and especially when the code is growing, you would have a hard time to predict the value of i.

Comment: do i need to do that when ever i need the value of i or i need to do it just once ?

Comment: It is not really a solution. Upon import, the code of the imported module will run immediately, giving you each time the same value for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to import `calculator1.py` in `calculater2.py` and call it from there.

The other solution is to serialize the data and write it to a file which you then can read from the other module. You can use for example pickle or json.

See for example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html